# Trying to identify a couple of tiny ICs

Tags: identification

I'm trying to identify these tiny ICs. They're in a 0.8mm square 4 lead package. The pins seem to be something like:

- GND
- VBAT
- CE
- VOUT

VBAT comes from the battery and VOUT is a stable 3.0 volts. When CE is driven high, the output is enabled. I've tried searching for the designations but no luck. Some sort of LDO with an enable pin?

[image: 1st one]

[image: 2nd one]

Comment: http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/b8  http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/c1

Comment: I should have mentioned, it's a QFN style package, so 'leads' was... er.. misleading...

Answer (score 1):

I started by 1st 2 digit codes and found too many, then searched by package type and found these to be unregistered but used by Fairchild/ON Semi.

[This](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/fairchild-semiconductor/FDZ661PZ/3163283) is not the same chip, but getting close.

I can't tell by photo without dimensions but looks like a BGA package called **4-WLCSP (0.80x0.80)**

Good luck - at least I reduced the millions of possibilities to a few **[thousand](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/result?s=N4IgTCBcDaICwFoDqAZAwgZQAogLoF8g)**

Comment: Looks like a Richtek RT9013 LDO in SC-82 package, from your s-manuals link.